# How do I change my authentication from LDAP to JDBC to secure my applications

Tags: java, mysql, spring, authentication, spring-security

I've completed the Spring guide 
["Authenticating a User with LDAP"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/).

But I want to use my MySQL database to authenticate users instead of their test-server.ldif / LDAP method.
In my database I have users, user_roles and users_to_roles tables.

What steps do I need to take to go from here(authentication working from LDAP) to the same authentication working from MySQL?

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-authenticating-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

HomeController.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public @ResponseBody String index() {
        return "Welcome to the home page!";
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            UserDetailsService userAccountDao = null;
            auth.userDetailsService(userAccountDao).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
            /*  Replaced with the above as per suggestions
             * 
             * auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
                    .groupSearchBase("ou=groups").contextSource()
                    .ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");
        */
        }
    }
}
```

test-server.ldif

```
dn: ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: subgroups

dn: ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: ou=space cadets,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: space cadets

dn: ou=\"quoted people\",dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: "quoted people"

dn: ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: otherpeople

dn: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Ben Alex
sn: Alex
uid: ben
userPassword: {SHA}nFCebWjxfaLbHHG1Qk5UU4trbvQ=

dn: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Bob Hamilton
sn: Hamilton
uid: bob
userPassword: bobspassword

dn: uid=joe,ou=otherpeople,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Joe Smeth
sn: Smeth
uid: joe
userPassword: joespassword

dn: cn=mouse\, jerry,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Mouse, Jerry
sn: Mouse
uid: jerry
userPassword: jerryspassword

dn: cn=slash/guy,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: slash/guy
sn: Slash
uid: slashguy
userPassword: slashguyspassword

dn: cn=quote\"guy,ou=\"quoted people\",dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: quote\"guy
sn: Quote
uid: quoteguy
userPassword: quoteguyspassword

dn: uid=space cadet,ou=space cadets,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Space Cadet
sn: Cadet
uid: space cadet
userPassword: spacecadetspassword



dn: cn=developers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfNames
cn: developers
ou: developer
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: uid=bob,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=managers,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfNames
cn: managers
ou: manager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
uniqueMember: cn=mouse\, jerry,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org

dn: cn=submanagers,ou=subgroups,ou=groups,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: groupOfNames
cn: submanagers
ou: submanager
uniqueMember: uid=ben,ou=people,dc=springframework,dc=org
```

Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Edit----------
New class as per suggestions
UserAccountDao.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UserAccountDao implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
        // Execute database query to retrieve the user details. 
        // TODO create user bean implementing UserDetails. Return it. Test run yo!
        User user = new User("user", "user", true, true, true, true, null);
        //return userDetails;
        return user;
    }
}
```

Stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:378)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@1e59cda6 of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:176)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:221)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5185)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@1e59cda6 of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@1e59cda6 of type class org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter$CompositeObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.SecurityConfigurerAdapter.postProcess(SecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.configure(AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:96)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.DaoAuthenticationConfigurer.configure(DaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.configure(AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:37)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:376)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:236)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:283)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:68)
    at hello.WebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7db1920e.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:367)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7059302.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7059302$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1502345f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7059302.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider@1e59cda6': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:399)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.postProcess(AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor.java:60)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following to authenticate users using database:

**Modify `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`**:

```
auth.userDetailsService(userAccountDao).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
```

**Create `DAO` to talk to the database:**

```
@Component
public class UserAccountDao implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // Execute database query to retrieve the user details. 
        return <userDetails>;
}
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking <userDetails> should be replaced by a User bean containing sign in credentials user and password? Will it also require role information?

Comment: Yes it is `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` class.  It contains userName, password and granted authorities.

Comment: I attempted to return a User I initialised in the loadUserByUsername method but it's not working. I'll update my main post with stack trace and the changes you suggested.

Comment: I'm aware that this should be accessing my DB but assumed this would work if I hard code the instance just to test it first.

Comment: In the `init()` method you are passing `null` `UserDetailsService`. Autowire an instance of `UserDetailsService` and pass it to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

Comment: I finally got around to testing this. Belated thanks!